# Split the given array into K segments with Min-max sum

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I wrote this code for splitting an array S into k continuous segments, to minimize the largest sum among these k segments. Here S is a sequence so I cannot change the ordering of the elements. Here is the code:

```
def Opt(i, j):
    n = len(i)
    sum = [0]*(n+1)
    dp = [[0 for a in range(n+1)] for a in range(2)]
    for a in range(0,n):
        sum[a+1] = i[a] + sum[a]
        dp[0][a+1] = float('inf')
        dp[1][a+1] = float('inf')
    for a in range(1,j+1):
        for b in range(1,n+1):
            for c in range(a-1,b):
                dp[a%2][b] = min(dp[a%2][b], max(dp[(a-1)%2][c], sum[b]-sum[c]))
    return dp[j%2][n]

# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    S = [7,2,5,10,8]
    k = 2
    M = sum(S)/len(S)
    ans = Opt(S,k)
    print(ans)
```

This works perfectly well. But I would also like to return the segments for which I have calculated the min-max sum. For example, for the array `S = [3,3,7,33]` and `k=3` this algorithm returns the answer '33' but I want to return the segments as `[[3,3],[7],[33]]`. But I am not being able to do it. Can anybody help me?

Comment: If k=3 it will be [7,2,5],[10],[8] where the max sum is 7+2+5 =14. What is wrong here? It should be correct. Why it will be 15?

Comment: I can't add up, sorry!

Comment: You need to use a "traceback" technique. I'll post an answer but wanted to check I understood the problem first.

Comment: Ok please. Did you understand the problem now or need any further explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a **traceback** technique (not sure if that name is widely used, or just in bioinformatics).

As you fill in your dynamic programming matrix with the best possible **score** for each sub-problem, you also fill in a traceback matrix that encodes the **solution** for each sub-problem.

For your problem, the traceback could store the optimal break-points for the sub-arrays:

```py
def Opt(i, j):
    n = len(i)
    sum = [0]*(n+1)
    dp = [[0 for a in range(n+1)] for a in range(2)]
    tb = [[[] for a in range(n+1)] for a in range(2)]

    for a in range(0,n):
        sum[a+1] = i[a] + sum[a]
        dp[0][a+1] = float('inf')
        dp[1][a+1] = float('inf')

    for a in range(1,j+1):
        for b in range(a + 1,n+1):
            for c in range(a - 1, b):
                # if c should be a breakpoint, then...
                if max(dp[(a-1)%2][c], sum[b]-sum[c]) < dp[a%2][b]:
                    # ...update the best score, and...
                    dp[a%2][b] = max(dp[(a-1)%2][c], sum[b]-sum[c])
                    # ...update the solution
                    tb[a%2][b] = tb[(a - 1)%2][c] + [c]

    # extract optimal sub-arrays
    starts = tb[j%2][n]
    ends = starts[1:] + [n]
    sub_arrays = [i[s:e] for s, e in zip(starts, ends)]

    return sub_arrays


S = [7,2,5,10,8]

Opt(S, 2)              # ==> [[7, 2, 5], [10, 8]]
Opt(S, 3)              # ==> [[7, 2, 5], [10], [8]]
Opt([3, 7, 7, 33], 3)  # ==> [[3, 7], [7], [33]]
```

Comment: Ok but how can I get the full sub-array from the optimal breakpoint? Can you tell me? Should I just print the array until the next breakpoint right?

Comment: I edited to return the sub-arrays instead

Comment: Hello, your solution is not working for S = [3,4,2,2,6,7,13,10,43,50,5] and k=3. The middle segment is not getting any value. Can you find what is the problem? The optimal value is still correct which is 55. But the segmentation is wrong in this case.

Comment: It is not working for S=[3, 7, 7, 33] and k=3 also.

Comment: Got my `b` and `c` mixed up and somehow got lucky. Please check again.

Comment: Yes now it's working. Thanks a lot for your efforts!